# Temp sensor conversion

Tags: conversion

I'm looking for a formula to convert the decimal output of an LM95071 (temp sensor) to the temperature in Celsius.I know the step to be 0.03125 degrees C.

[LM95071 datasheet](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/texasinstruments2/lm95071.pdf)

Comment: Datasheet where?

Comment: updated post with datasheet

Comment: OK, now read it and ask about what you do not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page 9 holds the key: -

[image]

Look at the difference between 150 deg C and 0 deg C in the table - the digital difference is 4B00. In decimal this is 19,200 or 128 LSBs per degC. However, the last two bits are redundant so if they are chopped off, 32 LSBs equals 1 deg C or, 1 deg C = 0.03125 LSbs.

Answer (score 1):

The device has 14 bits of resolution, but provides a 16-bit data word.  The last two bits are always one.  So take the data word as a signed integer, do an integer divide-by-4 to get rid of the unused bits, and , multiply by .03125

Comment: great thank you. I still have an issue cause when I do the conversion with that method I get 192 degrees C and the chips maximum is 150 degrees C. I need to verify the data from the LM95071.